# Code not executing after Task Parallel library executes

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a logic on form load which is using parallel library, that is working fine. but after executing the tasks it is not opening the form. Can anyone help on this?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[3];
    var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    dummyList.ForEach(d =>
    {
        tasks[d] =
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ProcessPage();
        }, CancellationToken.None, 
           TaskCreationOptions.None,
           TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    });

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();                           
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you're deadlocking yourself.

You're instructing the tasks to run on the current synchronization context, which is your UI thread, via `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.
Then, you `Wait` on the main thread, synchronously blocking it.

Instead, you can asynchronously wait:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tasks = dummyList.Select(() => Task.Run(() => ProcessPage());
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    var form = new Form2();
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i want TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() also, because in the task am working with webbrowser control. which needs Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: Then don't open up new tasks at all, you'll have to run them synchronously. Or, split up the part the work that can be done via a background then do the rest on the UI thread. There is really no point in spinning up new tasks if they all need to execute on the UI thread.

Comment: actually i am scraping a website, which needs webbrowser to get javascript content and for processing multiple pages i need Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: @AmanKhanna Perhaps show us the code inside `ProcessPage`, so I can see what you're doing there.

Comment: @AmanKhanna web scraping doesn't need the WebBrowser control, just issue the HTTP requests to the target site using HttpClient or HttpWebRequest and read the responses.

Comment: @Panagiotis - that is right but i also want to get the html content rendered with ajax and javascript in the site.

Comment: @Aman Then why not use [Html Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)?

Comment: @Panagiotis - how can i fetch dynamic html content with htmlagilitypack.

Answer (score 0):

One of your tasks is probably stuck. Nothing will appear until all the tasks have completed due to your `WaitAll()`

Comment: even i removed waitall() it still is not opening the form